# LESS: Darken whatever color is already set on the element

Tags: css, less

Just started using LESS and it's amazing. I was wondering though, is it possible to darken whatever color it was assigned.

I have several themes on my site and when a link is active, I add it a class "active" which should darken the color and background.

Is something like this possible:

```
.active{
   background:darken(10%);
}
```

Without having to specify the background color...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

`.active{
   background:lighten(-10%);
}`

Not sure if that'd work though so what might be better is using:

`.active{
            filter: brightness(0.1);
            -webkit-filter: brightness(0.1);
            -moz-filter: brightness(0.1);
            -o-filter: brightness(0.1);
            -ms-filter: brightness(0.1);
        }`

(play around with the 0.1 value to get your desired effect)

Comment: the first code can not work. thats not how less works.
the 2nd may be ok.

Comment: yep it was a shot in the dark (pun intended) the second will work cross-browser

Answer (score 4):

darken (as the other functions) expects 2 parameters. first the color, second the amount to change it.
see http://lesscss.org/functions/#color-operations-darken

Since LESS is only a preprocessor for css (it creates css) what you want can not work. CSS has no way of getting a color of an element and then work with it.

While LESS uses JS to process the less files and create css, that usually wont happen client-side. In production you create the css-file once and deliver that.

You may want to look for a client-side js-solution if you really have no way of knowing what the color is.